# Linq To Sql, Complex Select

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I'm building a portal(it's my hobby project) and for my index (home) page i need to write specific query.

I want to get categories in the specified order. For each category i want to load N most recent articles that are attached to it. So basically my home page will looks like

```
Category 1            Category 2
Article title 1       Article title 1
Article title 2       Article title 2
....                  ....
Article title N       Article title N


Category 3            Category 4
Article title 1       Article title 1
Article title 2       Article title 2
....                  ....
Article title N       Article title N
```

My simplified domain model looks like this:

```
public class CategoryInfo
{
    public virtual Int64 ParentId? { get; set; }

    public virtual String Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Int32 DisplayOrder { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ArticleInfo> Articles { get; set; }
}

public class ArticleInfo
{
    public virtual String Title { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime Published { get; set; }

    public virtual Int64? CategoryId { get; set; }

    public virtual CategoryInfo { get; set; }
}
```

Category can have many articles related to it. Article can be uncategorized.

So i attempt to do it this way:

```
var query = _categoryService.GetCategories().Where(x => !x.ParentId.HasValue) // Getting only top level categories
                                            .OrderBy(x => x.DisplayOrder)     // Sorting
                                            .Select(x => x.Articles.OrderByDesc(a => a.Published).Take(N))
```

This doesn't work. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by using SelectMany like this:

```
categories.Where(x => !x.ParentId.HasValue) // Getting only top level categories
            .OrderBy(x => x.DisplayOrder) // Sorting
            .SelectMany(x => x.Articles.OrderByDescending(a => a.Published).Take(10))
            .GroupBy(x => x.Category);
```

you can iterate it like this:

```
        foreach (var group in query)
        {
            Console.Write(group.Key); //the category
            //group is an enumerable of articles
        }
```

Comment: What's the purpose of GroupBy operator here ?

Comment: the full expression could be evaluated as: get the top 10 articles of each category (so if you had 10 categories you'd have 100 articles). By grouping them back by category, now you have 10 results, one for each category. So I don't know how to explain this with other words, the GroupBy operator, groups your articles by category

Answer (score 0):

I think that the correct approach would be:

```
var query = _categoryService.GetCategories().Where(x => !x.ParentId.HasValue) // Getting only top level categories
                                            .OrderBy(x => x.DisplayOrder)     // Sorting
                                            .Select(x => new {
Category = x,
Articles = x.Articles.OrderByDesc(a => a.Published).Take(N))
});
```

The result will be a collection of anonymous objects. Each object will have 1 Category object and a collection of related Articles objects. This can become your display model.